# CorePlot AutoResize GraphHostingView

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, autoresize

I have two plots (overlaid with clear color background) which are updated every second while my app is running. I want the graph to autoresize when being updated. My question is: Is there a function for core-plot like the **Autoresize** of an `UILabel` (like when the content string is too long it shrinks the font size that everything is readable)? Or do I have to do it manually? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot space has method called `-scaleToFitPlots:` that will adjust the plot space to fit the data for all of the provided plots. For example, to scale the default plot space to fit all of the plots associated with a graph, use this statement:

```
[graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
```

Comment: Here i am getting the error "-[CPTMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6952b50" - like this, when set CPTXYPlotSpace for Plot. How do i get out from this.